# How to upload sources to local Maven repository

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Suppose I have a Maven 2 Java project on my local machine. I build the project `.jar` file and push it to my local Maven repo, using `mvn install`.

**Question:**

How can I force Maven to also push the project sources `jar` to the local repo?

This is useful if I'll use the above mentioned project as dependency while developing a new project, and can use the `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources` feature.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This snippet automatically installs / deploys a source jar from any install / deploy:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>[whatever version is current]</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Use this link to check for the [current version of the `maven-source-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-source-plugin)

Or from command line:

```
mvn clean source:jar install
```

Comment: wow, it so simple! was hard to find this on maven site, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the command line, without editing the pom?

Comment: @hertzsprung sure: `mvn clean source:jar install`

Comment: don't forget to use the latest plugin version. current latest version is 3.2.1

Comment: the funniest part is the order of plugins matters on command line ("source:jar install" works but "install source:jar" doesn't work for me, maven3.5.2/java8)

Comment: Does this also go for `deploy`?

Answer (score 6):

I have found a better answer, just add this on your pom.xml

```
 <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
```

And run from command line:

```
mvn install
```

Now maven install on your local repository jar and sources

Solution found on: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/generate-source-code-jar-for-maven-based-project/ (I'm not affiliated in any way)

Answer (score 2):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=hello-world-1.0.0.jar -Dsources=hello-world-1.0.0-sources.jar -DpomFile=hello-world-1.0.0.pom
```

Answer (score 1):

One addition to the above answer:

It still wasn't working correctly for me. The sources.jar was generated and available in the target folder but not in the local repository. The reason for that was that I specified the phase differently: `<phase>install</phase>` In this case the maven install plugin is executed first and copies the jar files into the local repo. Afterwards the source.jar is generated (and thus not copied).

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ foo ---
[INFO] Installing foo.jar into local repo
[INFO] Installing pom.xml into local repo
[INFO] Installing javadoc.jar into local repo
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ foo ---
[INFO] Building jar: foo-sources.jar
```

So it is important to specify an earlier phase than install (like it is correctly mentioned in the accepted answer).